# Windows Phone tilt effect using CSS3 and 3d transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Windows Phone has a nice "tilt" effect when you press a control. It tilts the control toward that point you clicked/touched

[image]

The effect is described here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/03/23/tilt-effect-for-windows-phone-controls.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/11/updated-tilt-effect.aspx

I wonder if such effect could be also done via CSS3 3D transformations with a little help of javascript (to find out the touched location)?

Comment: This is something you could easily find out by Googling using search terms similar to "CSS 3d transform"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css3 transforms

```
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1,  0, 0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/v2fn35br/)

```
<div id="button">Defaults (both 0.33)</div>

#button {
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #111;
    border: 2px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1,  50, 0);
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1,  50, 0);
}
```

I guess you would have to pick up the touch point to detect if you wanted it tilting to the left or right. Something like jQuery [.position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) could help you there.

Comment: Using the `matrix` form is perfectly valid, but arguably more confusing than using `skew`s and `rotate`s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. It seems WinJS has already a codepath that does exactly this, although only on the phone. But that is easily hackable to work on non-phone code paths too:

```
// Returns a CSS transformation to rotate and shrink an element when it is
// pressed. The closer the click is to the center of the item, the more it
// shrinks and the less it rotates.
// *elementRect* should be of the form returned by getBoundingClientRect. All
// of the parameters must be relative to the same coordinate system.
// This function was translated from the Splash implementation.
function tiltTransform(clickX, clickY, elementRect) {
    // x and y range from 0.0 thru 1.0 inclusive with the origin being at the top left.
    var x = _ElementUtilities._clamp((clickX - elementRect.left) / elementRect.width, 0, 1);
    var y = _ElementUtilities._clamp((clickY - elementRect.top) / elementRect.height, 0, 1);

    // Axis is perpendicular to the line drawn between the click position and the center of the item.
    // We set z to a small value so that even if x and y turn out to be 0, we still have an axis.
    var axis = {
        x: y - 0.5,
        y: -(x - 0.5),
        z: 0.0001
    };

    // The angle of the rotation is larger when the click is farther away from the center.
    var magnitude = Math.abs(x - 0.5) + Math.abs(y - 0.5); // an approximation
    var angle = magnitude * MAX_TILT_ROTATION;

    // The distance the control is pushed into z-space is larger when the click is closer to the center.
    var scale = 1 - (1 - magnitude) * MAX_TILT_SHRINK;

    var transform = "perspective(800px) scale(" + scale + ", " + scale + ") " + rotationTransform3d(angle, axis);

    return transform;
}
```